# function pointer to any member function with any number of arguments

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

because of specific reasons I want a function pointer that can point to any member function of the class and can be changed whenever I want. I thought of a setup like the following:

```
//#include <iostream>
//#include <functional>
#include <cstdarg>

class someclass{
public:
    someclass(){ func = trial; }
    template<typename T, typename... Args> void setfunc(T t, Args... args){
        func = t(args...);
    }
    void trial(){
        //do some stuff
    }
    void trying(int i){
        //do other stuff
    }
    template <typename T>void (someclass::*func)(Args...);

};

int main(){
    someclass c;
    (c.*(c.func))();
    c.setfunc(someclass::trying, 32);
    (c.*(c.func))();

}
```

Unfortunately C++ doesn't let me do that and instead gives me the error:

```
data member 'func' cannot be a member template
```

I read that you can't make templates of member variables and when I write

```
void (someclass::*func)();
```

and scram the `Args`-part in `setfunc()`, it works just fine for `trial()`, but not for `trying()`. So my question is: is there anyway to fix this, work around it or any other way I can try?

Temporarily I'm here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
class someclass{
public:
   someclass(){
        func = std::bind(&someclass::trial, std::placeholders::_1);
    }
    void setfunc(std::function<void(someclass&)> f){ func = f; }
    void trial(){
        //do some stuff
        //std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
    }
    void trying(int i){
        //do other stuff
        //std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
    }
    std::function<void(someclass&)> func;
};

int main(){
    someclass c;
    #c.func(); //!!!
    c.setfunc(std::bind(&someclass::trying, std::placeholders::_1, 32));
    #c.func(c); //!!!
}
```

My IDE marks the lines with the #

Comment: *because of specific reasons I want a function pointer that can point to any member function of the class* You may want to rethink that requirement. It doesn't sound clean.

Comment: Can you not just use function overloading?

Comment: How would you use such function pointer? What is the correct way to call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `std::function`, something like

```
class someclass{
public:
    someclass(){ func = &someclass::trial; }
    void setfunc(std::function<void(someclass&)> f){ func = f; }
    void trial(){
        //do some stuff
    }
    void trying(int i){
        //do other stuff
    }
    std::function<void(someclass&)> func;
};

int main(){
    someclass c;
    c.func(c);
    c.setfunc([](someclass& cl){cl.trying(32);});
    c.func(c);
}
```

Comment: @Nicol Bolas The OP's example code shows the parameters being bound at the time the pointer is set, which would allow `function` + `bind`.

Comment: Well, doesn't really work in my IDE (Visual Studio 2013). It tells me that there's no instance of a function taking someclass but rather someclass&

Comment: @Supergravitation: I think implementation provided with VS2013 for `std::function` doesn't support member function :/, so you have to change `func = &someclass::trial;` into `func = [](someclass& cl){cl.trial();}` (or `std::bind` equivalent).

Comment: `func = std::bind(&someclass::trial, std::placeholders::_1);` (and `c.setfunc(std::bind(&someclass::trying, std::placeholders::_1, 32));`) for the bind equivalent. g++ and clang support the initialization from member function. There are many IDE which allows to chose compiler.

Comment: @Jarod42 Can you give me that bind equivalent? Or can you name me an IDE that has got a copmpiler that has got functionalities like member functions? -- oh thanx!

Comment: @Jarod42 It still doesnt work :/ By now I'm there: -- look at my original post, lower section.

Comment: Works for gcc/clang [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02b2c9ab1886f22c). Do you have error with msvc or only with intellisense ?